# Expressing Determinant as Dot Product

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and define the linear function by $F(x)=det[x \ u \ v \ w]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Prove that there is a vector $z$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $T(x)=z \cdot x$ (dot product) for all $x$.

Please also find the components of $z$ in terms of $u,v,w$.

It makes sense to think about but I do not know where to start the proof, any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Think of the Laplace development of a determinant. This will work for any dimension.

Comment: I understand using Laplace development, how does that help me show that there is a unique vector z that satisfies det[x u v w] = ⋅ ?


x

Comment: I don't see the "unique" requirement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show that $F(\mathbf{x})$ is a linear function of $\mathbf{x}$ i.e. $F(k\mathbf{x}) = kF(\mathbf{x})$ and $F(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) = F(\mathbf{x}) + F(\mathbf{y})$

Comment: Its given in the problem that F(x) is a linear function, how does that help solve for a unique vector z that satisfies what is given?

Comment: Any linear function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a dot product $z.x$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The components of $z$ are just the images of the basis vectors $F((1,0,0,0)),F((0,1,0,0)) \dots$. So once you know $F$ is linear than you are done.